# How to horizontally align two buttons in html

Tags: html, button

I'm stuck working with this code on my company's site. I can't seem to figure out how to float the buttons with the code given.

```
<div class="text-center"><a class="text-center" href="/contact-us"><button class="btn btn-small btn-default"><i class="fa fa-envelope" aria-hidden="true"></i>CONTACT US</button></a></div>

<div style="text-align:center;"><a href="/send-flowers"><button class="text-center btn btn-default" style="padding-top:5px;"> <i class="material-icons" style="vertical-align: middle; font-size:1.25em;">local_florist</i>SEND FLOWERS</button></a></div>
```

[Current view. Links to imgur.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LAzkw.png)

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks so much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `float` **left or right** for horizontal align and for centralize use `margin` and as in bootstrap use `pull-left` or `pull-right class for the same.

like:

```
<div class="text-center pull-left"><a class="text-center" href="/contact-us"><button class="btn btn-small btn-default"><i class="fa fa-envelope" aria-hidden="true"></i>CONTACT US</button></a></div>

<div style="text-align:center;" class="pull-left"><a href="/send-flowers"><button class="text-center btn btn-default" style="padding-top:5px;"> <i class="material-icons" style="vertical-align: middle; font-size:1.25em;">local_florist</i>SEND FLOWERS</button></a></div>
```

Comment: That'll do it! Now they're just pixel to pixel next to each other. What'd be the best way to add a buffer between them and below them to help space it from the rest of the page if you don't mind the additional help.

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
<div class="center">

<button id="btn1">Button1</button>
<button id="btn2">Button2</button>

</div>
```

css

```
#btn1, #btn2
{
    width:20%;
    float:left;
}
```